# Bash. CGI post gives error 500. But works without AJAX.

Tags: shell, post, cgi

I'm trying to call an CGI page but the response comes in blank. It returns `error 500`. *If I just do the post without AJAX it works well.*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "content-type: text/html"
echo "lalala" > temp.file
cat temp.file
echo "
<br><b>Program:</b> $program  <br> \n"
echo "<html> adsdasd </html>"
```

Here are the headers:

```
Connection  close
Content-Length  535
Content-Type    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date    Thu, 19 Jan 2012 12:30:04 GMT
Server  Apache
Request Headers
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  16
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host    cgi:8888
Origin  null
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0
```

Comment: There is likely an error being added to the web server logs...what error message is given?

Comment: Have you run your shell script with `-x`? Or reduced the script down to just printing `<h1>hello world</h1>`? The headers look fine. Also, what is the webserver daemon you're using here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with

```
echo
echo
```

in the begin of the file.
It seems the server need those two echo before the header